# Foreach loop not reaching going further than first panel items

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, foreach, panel

It seems to me that my foreach loop is not reaching my second panel or something is making it skip the items in the loop.

Here is the creating of the panels and loop(I know the SQL is vulnerable to injections but for the sake of making the question shorter I just used SQL):

This is what is created for every product in the product table:

```
Label lbName = new Label();
lbName.Text = name + "\n" + row[7].ToString();
lbName.Height = 40;
lbName.Width = 150;
lbName.Name = name + row[7].ToString();
lbName.Location = new Point(ptX, ptY);
pt.Controls.Add(lbName);

Label lbID = new Label();
lbID.Text = row[0].ToString();
lbID.Height = 40;
lbID.Width = 150;
lbID.Name = "ID" + name + row[7].ToString();
lbID.Location = new Point(ptX, ptY);
lbID.Visible = false;
pt.Controls.Add(lbID);

TextBox txtStockCount = new TextBox();
txtStockCount.Text = "0";
txtStockCount.Height = 40;
txtStockCount.Width = 100;
txtStockCount.Name = "txtTS" + name + row[7].ToString();
txtStockCount.Location = new Point(ptX + 150, ptY);
txtStockCount.GotFocus += txtStockCount_GotFocus;
txtStockCount.KeyPress += txtStockCount_KeyPress;
txtStockCount.LostFocus += txtStockCount_LostFocus;
pt.Controls.Add(txtStockCount);

TextBox txtBroken = new TextBox();
txtBroken.Text = "0";
txtBroken.Height = 40;
txtBroken.Width = 100;
txtBroken.Name = "txtTB" + name + row[7].ToString();
txtBroken.Location = new Point(ptX + 300, ptY);
txtBroken.GotFocus += txtStockCount_GotFocus;
txtBroken.KeyPress += txtStockCount_KeyPress;
txtBroken.LostFocus += txtStockCount_LostFocus;
pt.Controls.Add(txtBroken);

TextBox txtRecieve = new TextBox();
txtRecieve.Text = "0";
txtRecieve.Height = 40;
txtRecieve.Width = 100;
txtRecieve.Name = "txtTR" + name + row[7].ToString();
txtRecieve.Location = new Point(ptX + 450, ptY);
txtRecieve.GotFocus += txtStockCount_GotFocus;
txtRecieve.KeyPress += txtStockCount_KeyPress;
txtRecieve.LostFocus += txtStockCount_LostFocus;
pt.Controls.Add(txtRecieve);

Label lbDifference = new Label();
lbDifference.Text = " 0 ";
lbDifference.Height = 40;
lbDifference.Width = 150;
lbDifference.Name = "lblDiff" + name + row[7].ToString();
                    lbDifference.Location = new Point(ptX + 600, ptY);
pt.Controls.Add(lbDifference);

Button btnConfirm = new Button();
btnConfirm.Text = "Confirm";
btnConfirm.Height = 30;
btnConfirm.Width = 80;
btnConfirm.Name = "btnConfirm" + name + row[7].ToString();
                    btnConfirm.Location = new Point(ptX + 750, ptY);
                    btnConfirm.Click += btnConfirm_Click;
pt.Controls.Add(btnConfirm);
```

and the reading the panels to update the database from the text boxes:

```
private void txtStockCount_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        TextBox txtB = (sender as TextBox);
        string name = txtB.Name.Remove(0,5);
        string prodID = "";
        string QtyToday = "";
        string QtyBD = "";
        string QtyRev = "";
        string table = "";

        foreach (Panel p in pnls)
        {
            IEnumerable<Label> labels = p.Controls.OfType<Label>();
            foreach (Label label in labels)
            {
                string Compare = label.Name.Remove(0, 2);
                if (name == Compare)
                {
                    prodID = label.Text;
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(Compare, @"^[a-hA-H]"))
                    {
                        table = "ProductHistoryAH";
                    }
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(Compare, @"^[i-qI-Q]"))
                    {
                        table = "ProductHistoryIQ";
                    }
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(Compare, @"^[r-zR-Z]"))
                    {
                        table = "ProductHistoryRZ";
                    }
                }
            }

            string sql = "Select * From Product WHERE ProdID = '" + prodID + "'";
            DataTable dtP = db.GetDataTable(sql);

            IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = p.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
            foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxes)
            {
                string name1 = textBox.Name.Remove(0, 5);
                label2.Text = name1;
                if (name == name1)
                {
                    if (textBox.Name == "txtTS" + dtP.Rows[0][1].ToString() + dtP.Rows[0][7].ToString())
                    {
                        QtyToday = textBox.Text;
                    }

                    if (textBox.Name == "txtTB" + dtP.Rows[0][1].ToString() + dtP.Rows[0][7].ToString())
                    {
                        QtyBD = textBox.Text;
                    }

                    if (textBox.Name == "txtTR" + dtP.Rows[0][1].ToString() + dtP.Rows[0][7].ToString())
                    {
                        QtyRev = textBox.Text;
                    }
                }
            }                

            string sql1 = "Select * From " + table + " WHERE ProdID = '" + prodID + "' AND ProdHDate = '" + DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() + "'";
            DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable(sql1);                

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                dbh.addnewstockhistory(ph);

            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {                    
                dbh.updatestockhistory(ph);
            }

        }            
}
```

Everything works 100%, it inserts and updates data with ease, with the first panel but no other textboxes on the other panels work.

The error lies in the foreach panel loop, the foreach loops inside the panel loop. It says there is a syntax error near the where of string sql1. But what i dont understand is that it works for the first panel but non of the other panels and it does have the prodID, I know this cause i placed the statement in a label just to see how it looks.

Please help. Ask for anything if you need.

Comment: I need a new laptop :)

Comment: That's a *huge* amount of code. Please reduce this to a [mcve]. (Is this *actually* a Winforms problem? Can you reproduce it in a console app?) Which of the 5 foreach loops in your code is causing problems?

Comment: Sorry guys, I will do so... the thing is, I don't know where the problem is :(... But i will try to reduce the code :)

Comment: Please try some debug steps: comment out the inner `foreach` loops and step through the outer loop, then take the inner code back in step by step and debug what happens.

Comment: Does the drpt["typeNo"] vary for each panel? These two statements look suspect "btnConfirm" + drpt["typeNo"].ToString(); AND if (row[6].ToString() == drpt["TypeNo"].ToString())

Comment: @PaulZahra Yes, each panel has its own "TypeNo" and "TypeDesc". You can ignore the btnconfirm but the " if (row[6].ToString() == drpt["TypeNo"].ToString())" thats vital, that ensures each product that is in that has that typeNo is placed in the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. All I had to do was check if the panel is the panel hosting the control by checking if the panel was the buttons parent and it worked.

```
if(p == btn.Parent)
{
    //Do my stuff
}
```

in my foreach panel loop.